# Vertical placement of a text in multirow cell of a longtable in the end of the page

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable, multirow

How to solve the placement problem of a vertical text in a `multirow` cell inside a `longtable` when it happens to fall in the end of the page and has to be continued in the next one?

I've updated the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68294341/longtable-with-multirows-and-multicolumns-in-latex) to show what I meant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow, graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]\vspace{10cm}

\begin{longtable}{|p{0.5in}|p{1.2in}|p{1.7in}|c|}
    \caption{Data Dictionary}\label{tab:summary}\\ 
    \hline
    \centering \textbf{Tables}&
    \centering \textbf{Columns}&
    \centering \textbf{Designation}&
    \textbf{Type}\\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{4}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Tables} &  \textbf{Columns}    &   \textbf{Designation} &   \textbf{Type} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot

\multirow{7}{*}[-5ex]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Building}}} &
\centering RI Building Ref
(Primary Key)&
\raggedright  The building reference in database&
text\\

\cline{2-4}

&\centering Building Name&
The building name&
text\\

\cline{2-4}

&\centering Development Name&
The development name to which the building belongs, if any.&
text\\

\cline{2-4}

&\centering Address&
The building street address&
text\\

\cline{2-4}

&\centering Submarket&
The submarket the building is located at.&
text\\

\cline{2-4}

& \centering Latitude&
The building latitude&
float\\

\cline{2-4}

&\centering Longitude &
The building longitude& 
float\\

\hline

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised in `multirow` package documentation: "care must be taken that the longtable doesn’t break the multirow entry when it is near the bottom of the page". If you want to prevent the pagebreak to occur in the middle an entry, it is advised to use `\\*` instead of `\\`. However, `\\*` does not work when followed by a `\cline`. It is necessary to load the `multirow` package using the `longtable` option "that redefines `\cline` so that the `\\*` will also work when followed by `\cline`".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[longtable]{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]\vspace{10cm}

\begin{longtable}{|p{0.5in}|p{1.2in}|p{1.7in}|c|}
    \caption{Data Dictionary}\label{tab:summary}\\ 
    \hline
    \centering \textbf{Tables}&
    \centering \textbf{Columns}&
    \centering \textbf{Designation}&
    \textbf{Type}\\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{4}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Tables} &  \textbf{Columns}    &   \textbf{Designation} &   \textbf{Type} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot

\multirow{7}{*}[-5ex]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Building}}} &
\centering RI Building Ref
(Primary Key)&
\raggedright  The building reference in database&
text\\*

\cline{2-4}

&\centering Building Name&
The building name&
text\\*

\cline{2-4}

&\centering Development Name&
The development name to which the building belongs, if any.&
text\\*

\cline{2-4}

&\centering Address&
The building street address&
text\\*

\cline{2-4}

&\centering Submarket&
The submarket the building is located at.&
text\\*

\cline{2-4}

& \centering Latitude&
The building latitude&
float\\*

\cline{2-4}

&\centering Longitude &
The building longitude& 
float\\

\hline

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```